# What ways do you describe changing from existence to non-existence?

Tags: word-usage, writing-style, repetition, phrasing

In a paper, I need to talk about things "coming into and leaving" existence multiple times. I feel this phrase is clumsy and there are definitely better ways of saying it that I just can't think of for some reason. I have used "entering and exiting" existence, "being created and removed", and the others. What is the obvious, clean way that I am missing? Is there one? Comes into and goes out of?

Comment: Without knowing your context it’s hard to say what’s applicable and want isn’t.  Materialize/dematerialize?

Comment: I'd probably say "blinking into and out of existence."  "Blinking into existence" is an idiom that indicates something being created out of absolutely nothing at all.  "Blinking out of existence" likewise is an idiom that indicates something utterly disappearing from the universe without a trace.

Answer (score 0):

The first word that came to mind is **transition** if you considered non-existence and emptiness as a stage too.

> ### transition
>
> a : passage from one state, stage, subject, or place to another :
>   CHANGE
>
> b : a movement, development, or evolution from one form, stage,
>   or style to another

[Source: Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transition)

Answer (score 0):

You can say *go in and out of existence* or *pop in and out of existence*.

For instance, when scientists talk about quantum fluctuation they use the phrase `popping in and out of existence`. You can observe it for yourself by searching **in and out of existence** to find this or similar usages.

Comment: Is this idiomatic? Where have you seen this before?

Comment: @marcellothearcane if you search **"in and out of existence"** in google, you can see countless examples.

Comment: See [how to answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), specifically the 'Provide context for links' section. We're a bit different to the sites you might be used to.